# Can the Contact Key for mobile push contacts be updated?

Tags: marketing-cloud, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilepush, mobilepush-ios

Currently we were using a unique number as Contact Key for Mobile Push contacts. (Not using email/phone number).
In SFMC, when I go to Contact Builder > All Contacts I can see all the information about Mobile Push contacts. i,e Contact key, Device ID etc…

I needed a clarification:

1. Does the contact key remain constant once created or is it possible to update the contact key with a new value  for the same Device ID?
2. What happens if I fail to set a contact key, then does salesforce automatically assign a unique number as contact key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, you can update the Contact Key.  Just set the value the same way you did previously.
2. When the SDK registers the device without a Contact Key a random UUID is generated for that device.
   2a. The (obvious?) downside to this is the SDK does not know about this value.
   2b. You can delay the initial registration until you set a Contact Key if the auto-generated (anonymous) value is a problem.  ref. https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/sdk-implementation/device-contact-registration.html